# Bind datapicker to an object in dd/MM/yyyy format

Tags: c#, xaml, datetime

I want to bind datapicker selected date to an object, the date presented by the datapicker is dd/MM/yyyy but the object recievs date in mm/dd/yyyy format.

```
Ob ob = new Ob();
public Window1()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   this.DataContext=ob;
}

public class Ob
{
        public string Data { get; set; }
}


<DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="datePicker1" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Data}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" />
```

I also tried this:

```
<DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="datePicker1" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Data,StringFormat=0:dd/MM/yyyy}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
           DateTime dt = new DateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Year, dateTimePicker1.Value.Month, dateTimePicker1.Value.Day);    
           string[] formats = dt.GetDateTimeFormats();    
           return(formats[0]);
```

Have look on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w.aspx) for more formats.

Comment: I want to use dd/MM/yyyy  as datapicker returns, datapicker returns ok